# How can i list a NFT?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, metaplex, nft

I'm building a marketplace for 1/1-NFT's. I'm trying to create a listing mechanism, which sends the metaplex-NFT to a PDA from where it can be bought, from someone else.
To unlist it the pda has to send it back to the owner.

(Optionally the pda should also have a bidding function, but not neccessary:)

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `Approve` and `Revoke` instruction from the token program to request the NFT owner to approve/revoke your program's PDA as a delegate.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#approve
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#revoke

You can then use Metaplex's `FreezeDelegatedAccount` instructions to prevent the owner of an NFT from transferring it while listed. And the `ThawDelegatedAccount` instruction to unfreeze.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/faq#freeze-authority
https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#freeze-the-token-account-as-a-delegate
https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#thaw-the-token-account-as-a-delegate

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Auction House. [link](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/auction-house/)
You can explore the Code and the docs and check if it helps